# Влияние санкций на ruSO

Tags: обсуждение, хэшкод

Мы вот сейчас переехали на чужие сервера. Насколько я понимаю, Stack Overflow на русском стал собственностью Union Square Ventures, Index Ventures, Bezos Expeditions и там, наверное, еще кучи инвесторов Stack Overflow (вернее, он изначально был таковым, мы просто добровольно влили в него свою базу знаний и "уникумов").

А что, если завтра политики дадут им указания прервать отношения с русским сообществом, неважно под каким предлогом?

Есть ли возможность отката на сервера HashCode в такой непростой ситуации?

Быть может, следует заранее обеспокоиться созданием какого-то фонда резерва, создание условий для такого перехода: потенциальные инвесторы, резервные серверные мощности, просто люди, которые будут работать над этой проблемой (программисты, в том числе), может, что-то еще... чтобы это не было для нас неожиданностью.

Comment: Скорее наши прикроют. А тема, как это ни грустно, актуальная.

Comment: @avp: да, гораздо больше верится в возможность такого шага со стороны наших вождей.

Comment: Думаю, наши (политики) даже не вкурсе о существовании `ruSO`, а некоторые - и о `SO`. К тому же, выгоды с нашей стороны нет ни какой.

Comment: Дело тут не в ru.SO, а в хранении контента на иностранных серверах. Пока поползновения только на *личные данные*, но ... возможно это только начало.

Comment: Ну... Надо написать парсер ru-SO и всё куда-нить слить, постоянно обновляя. И в случае чего вернуть на родину) Но у Николаса, полюбому есть доступ к бекапам `SO`, так что, думаю, проблем с восстановлением/переносом не будет. Разве что юридические права на вопросы/ответы.

Comment: @mega На ruSO очень много разработчиков, причем хороших. Если даже не на хешкод, то в случае чего запилим что то новое :)

Comment: 2avp Тут нет наших персональных данных.

Comment: Думаю, что стоит с таким вопросом обратиться к юристу (возможно, не нам, а администрации). Если требования о хранении личных данных на сервере в российской юрисдикции и вправду будут, не вижу больших проблем в этом (мы же не политический клуб тут, правильно?)

Comment: @VladD, но на русском тут общаются не только жители/граждане РФ.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Судя по всему, ко всем текущим вопросам-ответам придется добавить исходную ссылку (исходя из [новой лицензии](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2265/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F-mit-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-stack-overflow)). И сможет ли переварить эти базы движок на `hashcode`?

Comment: @mega, ну, допилить-то всегда можно... Ну или просто скрипт адаптации SO-данных в формат ХэшКод-овских данных)

Comment: Допилить конечно можно, но, насколько я понимаю, движок оч. продвинут в сравнении, с `ХэК`, а там как раз была проблема отсутствия должной его поддержки. Т.е. сейчас рассуждать, мол "допилим", "легко" - можно, но надо исходить из реалий сегодняшних, т.к. народ просто разбежится, недождавшись своих героев. Так уже было.

Comment: @RihardBrugekhaim, а я и не говорил о том, что мы **уже** попадаем под **существующие** ограничения. Вопрос в том, насколько далеко может зайти политика изоляционизма. На самом деле, конечно, через пару месяцев после прикрытия, скажем гугла, гита, а особенно доступа к фирменной доке окажется, что IT в заднице, и придется откручивать назад, но потери на таком повороте неизбежны.

Comment: @mega, кроме проблем с допиливанием есть такая простая проблема, как сервер(а) с электричеством и т.п. материальные затраты.

Comment: @avp, конечно, и это оч. важно

Comment: добавил предложение в вопрос

Comment: @Nofate: Но это же не мешает SO не нарушать законы страны своего пребывания и выдавать данные нерезидентов правоохранительным органам по их запросу?

Comment: @RihardBrugekhaim _"Тут нет наших персональных данных."_ -- если у части пользователей указаны реальное имя и мейл, то это персональные данные (ПД). и надо уведомить роскомнадзор об обработке ПД в соответствии с Федеральным законом РФ № 152-ФЗ, иначе может быть нехорошо.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

В своей истории ХэшКод лишь первые полтора года располагался на виртуальном сервере в России. Летом 2012го мы переехали на выделенный сервер под управлением компании Хетцнер, которая находится в Германии. Уверен, если бы сообщество не мигрировало бы на платформу Stack Exchange, мы бы все еще пользовались услугами Хетцнер'а.

Но это не важно, так как *на самом деле, на сайте нет персональных данных*. Перед миграцией я общался с юристом, который однозначно дал понять, что мы не храним никаких персональных данных участников.

Если все-таки возникнут какие-то недоразумения, сообществу доступен дамп всей базы знаний уже сейчас.

**Обновление**

Как мне объяснил юрист, ПД – это данные, которыми можно адресовать конкретного реального человека (например, паспортные данные или сочетание ФИО и адреса проживания). Для регистрации на сайте необходимо указать адрес электронной почты и псевдоним – эти данные не являются персональными.

На сайте нет никаких закрытых данных. Все публикуемое находится открытом доступе, за исключением адреса электронной почты и переписки с модераторами, в котором кроме критики в наш адрес ничего нет.

На мой взгляд, идея блокировки сайта выглядет крайне сомнительно. Все же, если появится реальная вероятность столь ошибочного поступка, я вынесу этот вопрос на обсуждение с коллегами. Уверен, мы сможем разрешить ситуацию.

Comment: _"на сайте нет персональных данных"_ -- если у части пользователей указаны реальное имя и мейл, то это персональные данные (ПД). и надо уведомить роскомнадзор об обработке ПД в соответствии с Федеральным законом РФ № 152-ФЗ

Comment: и если у модераторов есть доступ к ПД, то они должны подписать документы о неразглашении и т.д. -- все это указано в 152-ФЗ

Comment: _"Если все-таки возникнут какие-то недоразумения"_ -- их не должно быть если зарегистрироваться в реестре оперторов персональных данных в роскомнадзоре.

Comment: Позиция по поводу "размещения ПД за пределами РФ" понятна, но я, честно говоря, об этом не думал, когда задавал вопрос. По поводу возможной инициативы из штатов и наших скромных технических возможностей на Хешкоде ничего не добавите?

Comment: @Stack Модераторы соглашаются с «соглашением модератора» прежде чем получать доступ к инструментам.

Comment: @mega Пожалуйста, подскажите, ответил ли я на ваш вопрос? Возможно я что-то упустил?

Comment: Спасибо, ответ понятен. Да, наверное, тема раскрыта. Судя по ответу, ни какой подготовки к такому событию не предполагается.

Comment: @mega Как мне кажется, в этом нет надобности сейчас. Если будет видно, что что-то плохое может случиться, мы сразу активизируем необходимую деятельность.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky _"Модераторы соглашаются с «соглашением модератора»"_ -- если соглашение соответствует требованиям 152-ФЗ, то это хорошо. как я помню в законе какие-то дополнительные требования к тем, кто занимается обработкой ПД (в это понятие много чего входит; см. сайт роскомнадзора). если не соблюдать все требования, то может быть такая ситуация: email в роскомнадзор -> прокуратура -> суд и блокировка сайта до полного устранения нарушений. email может написать любой гражданин РФ, но его не будут рассматривать пока не установят личность заявителя. не слушайте юристов, почитайте закон.

Comment: @Stack: Мне как-то сомнительно, что _моя_ интерпретация закона лучше/точнее/правильнее, чем интерпретация профессионального юриста.

Comment: @VladD _"Мне как-то сомнительно, что моя интерпретация закона лучше/точнее/правильнее, чем интерпретация профессионального юриста"_ -- а вы читали 152-ФЗ? там интерпретировать нечего. все четко написано по пунктам. правда читать формулировки с непривычки будет нелегко.

Comment: @Stack: Я больше знаком с немецким законом :) Там без 5 лет обучения юриспруденции не разобраться. Даже не прочитать.

Comment: @VladD _"Там без 5 лет обучения юриспруденции не разобраться."_ -- это так только кажется. я тоже думал, что надо слушать юристов, и тем более, зарегистрированных в минюсте адвокатов. но стал читать сам. в итоге, нашел нужные формулировки и доказал компании, у которой несколько офисов, большой штат, профессиональные юристы, что они не правы. теперь у них много дел, а я отдыхаю и отвечаю на ruSO :)

Comment: @Stack: Хорошо вам! А Николас и я пока вынуждены работать, потому что не можем разобраться в законах лучше юристов.

Comment: @VladD _"А Николас и я пока вынуждены работать, потому что не можем разобраться в законах лучше юристов."_ -- т.е. если разберетесь, то перестанете работать? :) а про юристов подумайте: они получают деньги за каждый поход в прокуратуру, в суд. думаете юрист хочет избежать все эти походы?

Comment: @Stack: Ну, вы же разобрались, и можете отдыхать? ;-)

Comment: @VladD _"вы же разобрались, и можете отдыхать?"_ -- да, отдыхаю от чтения законов, потому что получил уведомление о том, что прокуратура передала материалы в суд, и это все ко мне никак не относится. но "машина" работает и наверное через месяц придет новое уведомление.

Comment: « и переписки с модераторами, в котором кроме критики в наш адрес ничего нет.» — ха, это точно.